# Appending ng-select on button click

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular-ngselect

I am using ng2-select in my template for selecting the items, there is a button named "Add" which when click should show another select field with list of other categories of items. For this the simplest version of my code looks like this:

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'client-user-detail',
templateUrl: `<div #one> 
              <ng-select #selectRole [allowClear]="true" 
              [multiple]="true" (data)="refreshValue($event)" 
              (selected)="onSelectRole($event)"
              (removed)="removed($event)"
              (typed)="typed($event)"
              placeholder="Choose/Search">
             </ng-select>                                   

            <button [disabled]="isDisable"
                    class="btn btn-default" 
                    (click)="add()"> 
                    <i class=" fa fa-save"></i>
                      Add
            </button>


  `,
  styleUrls: ['clientuserdetail.component.css']
  })

   export class TestComponent {
   @ViewChild('selectRole') public select: SelectComponent;
   @ViewChild('one') d1:ElementRef;

    constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer
    ) { }

   add() {
   let htmlText = `<ng-select #selectRole [allowClear]="true" 
                [multiple]="true" (data)="refreshValue($event)" 
                (selected)="onSelectRole($event)"
                (removed)="removed($event)" (typed)="typed($event)" 
                placeholder="Choose/Search">
                </ng-select>`;

   this.renderer.invokeElementMethod
     (this.d1.nativeElement,'insertAdjacentHTML',
      ['beforeend',htmlText]);

    }

 }
```

The above code doesn't create a select field. 
I read somewhere about component Resolver can be useful in such circumstances but I didn't grasp clear way to use it. If there is anyone who can simply explain me about how this problem can be solved, I will be very grateful. I need a clear illustration about how the components can be dynamically added or appended in angular 2. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to answer exactly with the way you are trying to add a field, I would recommend instead to put your **ng-select** inside an **ngFor** that your **add()** function would **increment** and remove all the **viewChild**.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * Created by lejendarm on 08/08/17.
 */


class Role {
  id: number;
  label: string;

  /* I'm not sure about the need of a constructor */
  constructor() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.label = '';
  }
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'client-user-detail',
  template: `<div *ngFor="role in roles"> 
              <ng-select [allowClear]="true" 
              [multiple]="true" (data)="refreshValue($event, role)" 
              (selected)="onSelectRole($event, role)"
              (removed)="removed($event, role)"
              (typed)="typed($event, role)"
              placeholder="Choose/Search">
             </ng-select>                                   
            </div>
            <button [disabled]="isDisable"
                    class="btn btn-default" 
                    (click)="add()"> 
                    <i class=" fa fa-save"></i>
                      Add
            </button>`,
  styleUrls: ['clientuserdetail.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
  private roles: Array<Role>;

  constructor(
  ) {
    this.roles = [new Role()];
  }

  add() {
    this.roles.push(new Role())
  }

  refreshValue($event, role) {}
  onSelectRole($event, role) {}
  removed($event, role) {}
  typed($event, role) {}
}
```

PS: Even if there is no direct link with your issue, I would use *template* instead of *templateUrl* and close the div #one to show a better code.

Comment: Can you please try to explain it with simple example? Thank You

Comment: I am not asking about pushing the role in array. What I am asking about is appending the ng-select. For example, if I am using first ng-select for roles of application 1, if I click add button, next ng-select should be appended to first and the second one should contain roles for application 2 and so on.. It is not about pushing the roles. It is about appending the select field.

Comment: I got your point, but this code will append a new select field every time you click on the add button"